# lamp stack on IBM Power 8

Tags: lamp, ibm

I'm planning the transition of sugarcrm ce on a ubuntu partition installed on a ibm power 8.
Can anyone tell me if I have problems with the lamp stack (apache, php, mysql)?
Does anyone have experience on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM POWER8 processor understands the instruction set called "ppc64el" in Linux. If you can get to run Ubuntu on this machine then you can also install a LAMP stack since the latter is available for all the same processor architectures as Ubuntu's base system. You can look at the individual packages to see if they're available for your architecture (see the download section at the bottom):

- [apache2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apache2)
- [mysql-server-5.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mysql-server-5.7)
- [libapache2-mod-php7.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libapache2-mod-php7.0)

Almost all open-source software packages are available for all architectures (supported by Ubuntu) but many proprietary packages aren't.

As for *[SugarCRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SugarCRM)*, it appears to be written in PHP, which means it runs anywhere where you can run a suitable PHP interpreter. PHP is available under an open-source software license and Ubuntu provides packages for the ppc64el architecture (see above).